# SQL Error(4104): The multi-part identifier "t1.ENTRY_DATETIME" could not be bound

Tags: sql

The multi-part identifier "t1.ENTRY_DATETIME" could not be bound. What am i not doing right?

```
SELECT t.ACNT_CODE,
       t.DESCR, 
       CASE t."STATUS" 
          WHEN '1' THEN 'HIDDEN'
          WHEN '2' THEN 'SUSPENDED'
          WHEN '3' THEN 'CLOSED'
          ELSE 'OPEN' 
       END as STATUS, 
       DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE() ,(CONVERT(DATE, t1.ENTRY_DATETIME))) AS DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CHANGE_DATE, 
       (SELECT MAX(t1.ENTRY_DATETIME) FROM [GRN_A_SALFLDG] t1
        WHERE t1.ACCNT_CODE = t.ACNT_CODE  ) AS LATEST_ENTRY_DATE
FROM GRN_ACNT t
```

Comment: Look at your DATEDIFF function. It's not going to know what t1 is yet.

Comment: how do i correct this please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full 100% answer, I don't know your table structure. But might help you get started by seeing the join.

```
SELECT t.ACNT_CODE,
       t.DESCR, 
       CASE t."STATUS" 
          WHEN '1' THEN 'HIDDEN'
          WHEN '2' THEN 'SUSPENDED'
          WHEN '3' THEN 'CLOSED'
          ELSE 'OPEN' 
       END as STATUS,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE() ,(CONVERT(DATE, t1.ENTRY_DATETIME))) AS DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CHANGE_DATE,
FROM GRN_ACNT t
LEFT JOIN RGN_A_SALFLDG t1 
ON t.ACNT_CODE = t1.ACCT_CODE
```

Looking at the MAX used in your subquery, I'm guessing that multiple dates can be found for ACNT_CODE. If that's the case, which ENTRY_DATETIME are you expecting for DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CHANGE_DATE?  It's hard to give a complete solution without knowing how your data is setup.

Comment: You are right. I expect ENTRY_DATETIME  to be the latest entry date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ACNT_CODE,
       t.DESCR,
       CASE t."STATUS" 
          WHEN '1' THEN 'HIDDEN'
          WHEN '2' THEN 'SUSPENDED'
          WHEN '3' THEN 'CLOSED'
          ELSE 'OPEN' 
       END as STATUS,t.DFLT_CURR_CODE,
       ISNULL(t.DFLT_CURR_CODE,'') AS CURRENCY_CODE,
       MAX(t1.ENTRY_DATETIME) AS LATEST_ENTRY_DATE
       INTO #ACCOUNT_CODE_
FROM GRN_ACNT t
LEFT JOIN [GRN_A_SALFLDG] t1 
ON t.ACNT_CODE = t1.ACCNT_CODE
GROUP BY t.ACNT_CODE, t.DESCR, t."STATUS", t.DFLT_CURR_CODE
ORDER BY t.ACNT_CODE ASC; 

SELECT a.ACNT_CODE, a.DESCR,a.CURRENCY_CODE,a.STATUS,CONVERT(DATE,a.LATEST_ENTRY_DATE) AS LATEST_ENTRY_DATE, ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE() ,(CONVERT(DATE, a.LATEST_ENTRY_DATE)))) AS DAYS_SINCE_LAST_ACTIVITY 
INTO #DORMANCY
FROM #ACCOUNT_CODE_ a
INNER JOIN GRN_ACNT t2 
ON t2.ACNT_CODE = a.ACNT_CODE
GROUP BY a.ACNT_CODE,a.DESCR,a.CURRENCY_CODE,a.STATUS,a.LATEST_ENTRY_DATE
ORDER BY DAYS_SINCE_LAST_ACTIVITY DESC;


SELECT * FROM #DORMANCY;
```